# Resrtict MS Access creation

Tags: group-policy, microsoft-access

Is it possible to restrict MS Access creation but still be able to view and execute Access files.

Comment: Can you add a few more words to that?

Comment: Belongs on Server Fault. (Based on Group Policy tag => this is an organisational thing, hence not Super User.)

Comment: Consider accepting answers to some of your questions.  You can do this by clicking the checkmark next to the correct answer for each question.

Comment: I don't think it's a ServerFault question at all. The keywords are wrong, as the only way to do this is in your connection method, not via group policy.

Answer (score 4):

Don't let those users install the full version of Access. Your developers can create files that can be run on a computer with the necessary run-time files but they would not be able to create/alter items in the file.

[Access 2007 Developer Extensions and Runtime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/bb229700.aspx)

Comment: This is an answer that belongs on SO.